# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 0 given

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "root"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","users"); // set database name

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysqli_select_db()($link, "users") or die("Couldn't select database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

Comment: error message is **very** clear

Comment: your  `mysqli_select_db` syntax is wrong

Comment: Why do you define `DB_NAME`, then hard-code the database when you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$db = mysqli_select_db()($link, "users") or die("Couldn't select database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

to

```
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't select database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

or alternatively get rid of that line and do this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
```